# VirtualKD + VBox > 4.3

Tags: debugging, kernel-mode

Is it any way to connect VirtualKD 2.8 to VBox > 4.3.

I googled it but the nearest result was [VBOX_WITH_VIRTUALKD](http://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Devices/Misc/VirtualKD.cpp) config flag and some change logs about [stub/loader](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-4.3#4.3.16).

---

OK, because of lack of information in my question, I try to explain my problem...

I start installing the VirtualKD from [Ref I](http://virtualkd.sysprogs.org/tutorials/install/) using VKD 2.8. exactly in step 2 it said

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'VirtualBox.VirtualBoxClass' ...

So I start googleing and i found a great article [Ref II](http://www.virtualroadside.com/blog/index.php/2013/03/11/virtualkd-2-8-with-virtualbox-4-2/). I compiled the C# code and ran it in the VirtualKD-2.8 directory. the first problem is gone but the virtual box said:

> Unable to load R3 "C:\VirtualKD-2.8\VBoxKD64.dll": Not signed ... (VERR_LDRVI_NOT_SIGNED)

Again I start googleing... the problem is for `VBox > 3.1`, it force signed dll loading in windows. so I signed the DLL by a self generated sign ( and of curse I added it to my trust list ). now the virtualbox braks with

> Unable to load R3 module "C:\VirtualKD-2.8\VBoxKD64.dll" None of 1 path(s) hav a trust anchor.: ... (VERR_CR_X509_CPV_NO_TRUSTED_PATHS).

so I used a globally trusted sign to do the job but I got a FATAL error from vbox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I think, someone else might have this problem, I have to answer my own question...

First. please read the question carefully ( it is long but worst it ).
Then...

As Virtual Box only accepts signed DLLs so you have to sign the 
*VBoxKD64.dll* and/or *VBoxKD.dll*. it is not easy to find a trust sign so avast guys make a pre-signed virtual-kd available for download [here](http://public.avast.com/~hnanicek/VirtualKd.zip)

Now we have another problem. Virtual Box will not load DLLs that are not owned by *NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller* so we have to add Virtual-KD directory to it's kingdom. ( read [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404240.aspx) if you have no ida about what I say )

Also it is a good description in the avast package named *Install.txt*.

Comment: The Avast link you provided doesn't have a signed copy of the driver in the .zip ?

Comment: You are right. my problem was installing Virtual-KD on Virtual Box. It doesn't need Virtual-KD driver to be signed... some useful information about your problem is present at VKD forum.